# Redireccionar Admin/User despues de Logear

Tags: php, laravel-8, redirección

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto web usando `laravel 8` resulta que estoy atascado ya que cree el login y algunas rutas pero necesito que si logeo como ***admin*** entre directamente al **dashboard** y si logeo como usuario entre a una página de bienvenida.
He estado viendo varias teorías y tutoriales pero usan métodos diferentes entonces decidí dividir mis rutas las de usuarios normales en el archivo ***web.php*** y las rutas admin en un archivo ***admin.php***. Pero resulta que en el archivo **LoginController.php** que es donde maneja las redirecciones no redirecciona como deseo, si logeo como usuario normal redirige a la pagina de bienvenida pero si logeo como admin no redirige al dashboard sino a la misma pagina de bienvenida.
Agregare el código de los archivo:

**web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\GasolinaController;
use App\Http\Controllers\CuentaController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('index');

Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('welcome');

Route::resource('gasolina', GasolinaController::class);

Route::resource('cuentas', CuentaController::class);
```

**admin.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\HomeController;


Route::get('/dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\HomeController::class, 'index'])->middleware('isAdmin')->name('admin.index');
```

**LoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Auth;
class LoginController extends Controller
{

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $username = 'user';
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
    protected function redirectTo(){
        if (Auth::user()->admin == True){
            return route('admin.dashboard');  // admin path
        } else {
            return route('welcome');  // normal user path
        }
    }
    public function username(){
        return 'user';
    }

}
```

y creo que este archivo es importante tambien:

**RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //public const HOME = '/';

    /**
     * The controller namespace for the application.
     *
     * When present, controller route declarations will automatically be prefixed with this namespace.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    // protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
            Route::middleware('web', 'auth')
                ->prefix('admin')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
        });
    }
}
```

**Edito:**

AdminMiddleware.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->admin == True)
        return $next($request);

    return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: En laravel tienes un middleware ya creado para hacer eso mismo, échale un vistazo a la carpeta de middlewares y mira el "RedirectIfAuthenticated"

Answer (score 0):

Para controlar ésto, debe usar un midleware, ya que el midleware está a la mitad del proceso con el request, al crear un midleware debe validar con una columna que debe exisitir para  los usuarios llamada role, donde unos tendran rol user o rol admin, el midleware debe validar a qué rol pertenece el usuario que se está logueando, y él esel que hace el redirect(), para que funcione, debe asignar en su ruta de login el midleware que creó, y listo.

Comment: Pues si tengo un middleware que creo que hace esa función que mencionas editare la pregunta para que puedan verlo, pero creo que no estoy incluyendo algo en las rutas porque no hace la redirección.

Comment: if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->admin){
        return $next($request);
}else {
    return redirect('/'); }